# Need to check most used linux apps of all time on my machine

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, fedora

I need to get list of all apps which I use most.
I do not want `ps aux` or `top` etc.
Need to make a shell script which will show frequently used apps of all time like google chrome , firefox , gedit etc.In this list need to show apps which I have opened , but not those which is default opened by OS
If possible, I want to list down running time of app, idle time.I have Fedora and Ubuntu.So no issue with OS.
Please suggest me some commands, to fulfill my purpose.

Comment: Why don't you want to use those tools? Using those tools you can monitor every time a user (not the kernel) opens a process, how much time it ran for and its idle time...

Comment: Normally, there is nothing that keeps a history of every command ever run, along with statistics on runtime, memory use, etc. You could facilitate that by writing a wrapper script that you run in place of every app you are interested in tracking, but it can't recall the past, so it could only start tracking from now forward. And even suggesting it makes me feel a bit dirty - it's probably not a really good idea. What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Maybe there are better ways than this...

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu  , which tool?

Comment: @twalberg , I need to create something like windows.When you press start only frequently used processes are seen.If I get script then will create interface.

Comment: I think if you use KDE or Gnome (at least more recent versions), it may already do this, but I may be mistaken - it may just track the most recently used, not necessarily the most frequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [lastcomm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/lastcomm.1.html) to prints out information about previously executed commands.  If
       no  arguments  are specified, lastcomm will print info about all of the
       commands in acct (the record file).

Answer (score 0):

Just enable process accounting in your system. There are a lot of information about that over the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for relevant answer. But looks like need to write custom shell & store everything in it , to get the history.